# Sending data via ajax with multiple inputs having the same name

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to accomplish the following using jQuery.

I have 7 inputs, one for each day in the week. The html for this is generated server side.
For each day I have a text input and a link for submitting the text for that day only via ajax to the server.

So far I have

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function(){
       $('.add_dish').click(function(){
          var mydata = $('form input[name=user_input]').val();
          window.alert(mydata)

          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/add',
            data: mydata,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
              if(result == "true"){
              }else{
              }
            }
          });
       });
    });
</script>
```

Server side generated code:

```
<h1>First day</h1>
<form>
<input type="text" name="user_input">
<a href="#" class="add">Add</a>
</form>

<h1>Second day</h1>
<form>
<input type="text" name="user_input">
<a href="#" class="add">Add</a>
</form>

<h1>Third day</h1>
<form>
<input type="text" name="user_input">
<a href="#" class="add">Add</a>
</form>
```

When I click `Add` <strike>the alert box is empty</strike> the value of the the input of the first day is always displayed. How can it be changed to reflect the selections of the element in the *same* `<form>` as the submitting link is in?

**EDIT**:
Highlighted the second part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using jQuery selector the wrong way.

it should be like :

```
 var mydata = $('form input[name=user_input]').attr('value','something');
```

and if you just want the value of the input box to put in `mydata` :

```
var mydata = $('form input[name=user_input]').val();
```

**EDIT :**

For iterating on all the inputs with same name you have to use `.each()`:

```
    $('.add_dish').click(function(){

              $('form input[name=user_input]').each(function(){
              var mydata = $(this).val();
              window.alert(mydata);
              });


              $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/add',
                data: mydata,
                cache: false,
                success: function(result) {
                  if(result == "true"){
                  }else{
                  }
                }
              });
           });
```

References :

[**jQuery Input Selector**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

[**jQuery Class Selector**](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

[**jQuery `.each()`**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Comment: That helped. But this will always display the data of the first input.

Comment: This does indeed iterate through all the input boxes, but is there a way of only getting the value of the input box in the same `<form>` scope as the link that invoke the ajax function?

Comment: Figure it out with some `id`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to select element using class name but "user_input" is not a class name:) Use http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/